# C# Form Button added via code doesn't work on Click

Tags: c#

I got a form. At Designer I wrote

```
public Button dugme = new Button();
```

and

```
this.Controls.Add(dugme);
        dugme.Location = new Point(100, 300);
        dugme.Size = new Size(400, 50);
        dugme.Text = "Hesapla";
```

after that I went to Form1 and wrote

```
private void dugme_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("String");
    }
```

But when I press the button it doesn't work. And not just in these function, I wrote different things too. How can I fix that?

Comment: `dugme.Click += (snd, evt) => { MessageBox.Show("String"); };`

Answer (score 3):

I think you miss that binding `Click` event for your `dugme` Button.

Which might add to `InitializeComponent` method.

```
dugme.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.dugme_Click);
```

so the part of the code might look as below.

```
this.Controls.Add(dugme);
dugme.Location = new Point(100, 300);
dugme.Size = new Size(400, 50);
dugme.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.dugme_Click);
dugme.Text = "Hesapla";
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing an android app or something like that, you have to add this line in your oncreate :

```
$btnVar$.Click += function;
```